# OnTouch locations tablets vs. phone

Tags: android, screen-orientation, touch-event, device-orientation

I made a particle system that was designed for a tablet..  particles follow finger movement etc. anyways.. I implemented the gyroscope so when you tilt the tablet whatever direction.. all the particles fall to that direction.  In the manifest I locked it down to landscape view.

So then I loaded it up on a Samsung Intercept.  When I moved that screen around nothing was going in the correct direction at all..  So what I did to fix the situation is

```
if (width<800)  // My tablet width is obviously 800 phone is much less 
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
else
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

this fixes  my problem.. but I'm unsure if this is for all phones?  My samsung intercept is only for development and it's a POS IMO.  Is it the phone or is this just how it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some devices have a natural orientation of portrait and some have a natural orientation of landscape. This will affect the default sensor coordinate system for the device. Take a look at this post from the Android Developers blog for more details and solutions: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html

Comment: I'm going to have to push my app to a couple different phones and double check.. I will debug the values later.. but I got the feeling that the x and y axis flipped between phoen to tablet.  This blog is about a year old (prior to the more widespread nature of tablets)

Comment: I assure you that the post I linked was written with the current generation of Android tablets in mind. :) They were in development at the time and this post was made to point out this information early.

Comment: can you think of a better way to decide orientation (I'm assuming it would have to be in the java).  I'm curious how the new 7" tablets running on OS 2.x define orientation.